# custom directive in cell template in ui-grid angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I define a ui-grid to display data, and I define a cell template to set the column style. At the same time I also create a directive, here I just add it to the cell template. But the link function execution times is less than expectation.

Here's the whole thing on plunker: [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/y36frn9gYMGJEy1hJU7f)

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.grid']);

app.controller("dataCtrl", function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
var vm = this;
vm.gridOptions = {
    data: "ctrl.dataList",
    columnDefs: [
                {
                    name: "ID",
                    displayName: "User ID",
                    width: 200
                },
                {
                    name: "Name", displayName: "User Name",
                    cellTemplate: "<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" pop-tip><span style=\"margin-left:5px\">{{row.entity[\"Name\"]}}</span></div>"
                }
    ],
    enableRowSelection: true,
    enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
    multiSelect: false,
    noUnselect: true,
};

vm.dataList = [];
vm.loadData = function () {

    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        var user = {};
        user.ID = i;
        user.Name = 'user ' + i;
        vm.dataList.push(user);
    }
}

vm.loadData();
});

app.directive("popTip", function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        console.log($scope.row.entity.Name);
    }
};
})
```

You can get the browser log to view the time of link execution.

The result is that when the data amount is large that appears an vertical scroll, when we drag scroll bar the custom directive will not execute link function anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite likely that there is some optimization built into ui-grid, whereby they reuse already-linked row elements, rather than link new ones.

You could inspect that (and, it should get you what you need) by `$watch`-ing the changes in the scope:

```
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    //console.log($scope.row.entity.Name);
    $scope.$watch("row.entity.Name", function(v){
       console.log(v);
    });
}
```

This will display all the rows when scrolling.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qxPu3RWCHWhkG0gnLKc7?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, it make sense.Actually I need another attribute to get the row entity object. like $scope.dataSource=$scope.$eval($attrs.source), then I want output data according $scope.dataSource. But the result is also as begin. I have update the plunker. plnkr.co/edit/y36frn9gYMGJEy1hJU7f?p=preview

Comment: @RonSmith, are you asking something or just noting - I wasn't sure

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't describe clear. In order to reuse the custom directive, I want to get binding object according to another attribute, then use $scope.$eval to get it. But like this, the result is as start, i have update the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/y36frn9gYMGJEy1hJU7f?p=preview

Comment: what does it "the result is as start"? and if you want to reuse, I suggest using an isolate scope and pass the input directly

Comment: The link function execution also less than total times. I don't know why. Basically  I prepare use isolate scope, but there is another error with another three part library.

Comment: @RonSmith, I suggest asking another question. Comments don't allow for enough space to clarify the issue. But here's what I meant by isolate scope: http://plnkr.co/edit/FijIBTbV9eZeFbyLy5Xr?p=preview

Comment: I know you thought is correct, because the popTip directive will add some other directive attribute and it also need an isolate scope, so the app will throw an exception that multiple directive contention. I don't know how to resolve it ,so here I don't create isolate scope.

Comment: @RonSmith, `$scope.$eval` just gives you the object at the time of linking - it doesn't change. Use `$parse` instead: http://plnkr.co/edit/La1gQbwVLh0t3ObSZlxC?p=preview

Comment: Great, @@New Dev, I appreciate that you help me solve the difficult problem.  Thank you again.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue where I am examining the nested objects.  If any of these nested objects are prohibited then I am rendering 'prohibited' for that data point in the grid.  When I execute this logic via a $filter it works flawlessly.  When I try to execute this logic inside a directive it only works correctly for the first ~20 rows.  If you scroll down or sort the grid then the column representing the directives becomes disassociated with the actual rows.  While the $filter approach works it feels dirty since I'm also adding dom elements in the case of 'prohibited'.  Thoughts?